# Void SetGrade (int total) : [error: invalid use of void expression]

Tags: c++, void

I have code like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int total = 95;
    cout << "Grade is : " << SetGrade(total) << endl;
}
void SetGrade(int total){ 
     char Grade;
     if (total >= 90){
         Grade = 'A';
     }else if (total > 80 && total <= 89){
         Grade = 'B';
     }else if (total > 70 && total <= 79){
         Grade = 'C';
     }else if (total > 60 && total <= 69){
         Grade = 'D';
     }else{
         Grade = 'E';
     }
}
```

and the output is : error: invalid use of void expression.

Comment: A function with return type `void` doesn't return anything, so `cout << "Grade is : " << SetGrade(total) << endl;` makes no sense

Comment: This is not the error that this program will generate. Please post the actual code you tried to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The function you defined has void as return type. 
To pass it to the std::cout you need to pass something. E.g. like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int total = 95;
    std::cout << "Grade is : " << total2Grade(total) << std::endl;
}
std::string total2Grade(int total){ 
     std::string Grade;
     if (total >= 90){
         Grade = 'A';
     }else if (total > 80 && total <= 89){
         Grade = 'B';
     }else if (total > 70 && total <= 79){
         Grade = 'C';
     }else if (total > 60 && total <= 69){
         Grade = 'D';
     }else{
         Grade = 'E';
     }
     return Grade;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to procedure. Not function

Answer (score 0):

This is solved with :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int total = 95;
    cout << "Grade is : "; SetGrade(total);
    return 0;
}
void SetGrade(int total){ 
     char Grade;
     if (total >= 90){
         Grade = 'A';
     }else if (total > 80 && total <= 89){
         Grade = 'B';
     }else if (total > 70 && total <= 79){
         Grade = 'C';
     }else if (total > 60 && total <= 69){
         Grade = 'D';
     }else{
         Grade = 'E';
     }
     cout << Grade;
}
```